# Any screenshot application that supports HiDPI?

Tags: screenshot, dpi, kazam, gnome-screenshot

In a computer with a HiDPI screen (3200x1800), with Ubuntu 14.04 and Cinnamon, gnome-screenshot (3.10.1) captures images at half the resolution (1600x900), so the capture appears blurry. I've tried Kazam (1.4.4-1) and the behaviour is [the same](https://bugs.launchpad.net/kazam/+bug/1283424).

So far I've only had some success with KGrab, but the image gets sometimes corrupted, probably related to using Cinnamon.

Is there any other screenshot application that supports HiDPI?

Comment: Have you tried gimp?

Comment: I never knew that GIMP made screenshots. I have just checked it and I can confirm that GIMP 2.8.10 works perfectly with HiDPI. Thanks!

Comment: For the record: there are two bug reports for this issue in gnome-screenshot: Ubuntu's https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-screenshot/+bug/1394883 and upstream https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=743957

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gimp, in "File > Create > Screen Shot".